# How can I make a Variable True and check if the variable is true?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, boolean

EDIT

I think i formulated myself wrong,
the sword is an item you can obtain ingame, so the value starts at 0 (FALSE).
When the player obtains the sword, the variable goes to 1 (TRUE).
Now, after the variable is true, I want to be able to use

```
  choice /c 12 /n /m "What do you want to do?"
    echo.
    IF %errorlevel%==1 goto Continiue1
    IF %errorlevel%==2 goto Gameover1
    **IF %sword%==TRUE choice /c 3 /n /m "[SWORD] -Attack!"**
```

**IF %sword%==TRUE choice /c 3 /n /m "[SWORD] -Attack!"**

/EDIT

Please help me understand how I can return a value from a variable and use it later to check if the variable is true.
I am new to batch programming, so I'm still learning new things!

```
@echo OFF
:start
    set sword=False

    IF %sword%==True echo You have a sword!
    echo.
    IF %sword%==False echo You don't have a sword.
    echo.
    pause
```

I have been searching the web for two days without any luck.

Comment: What part of this isn't working? This works fine for me.

Comment: I edited the post, please take another look at it!  :)

Comment: That line is never going to be reached. The `"What do you want to do"` gives you only two options, and both of them `goto` somewhere else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set sword=true

:start
if %sword% equ true echo You have a sword.
if %sword% neq true echo You do not have a sword.
pause
```

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" - Created a user today.. Sorry ;P

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
@echo OFF
set "sword="
:start
IF defined sword (echo You have a sword!
   ) else (echo You don't have a sword.)
echo.
pause
```

Edit :

Then just use :

```
if not %sword%==0 goto:attack
```

Comment: I edited the post, please take anoter look at it. :)

Comment: Ok, but how can I make %sword% go to 1?

Comment: didn't expect goto or something.. But Sheldon Lee Cooper's answer works perfectly :) Thanks for the help :)